# C# - Given a string that is representing a numeric percentage, a way to extract the whole percentage?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert the string “39.9983%” into “39%” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984204/how-do-i-convert-the-string-39-9983-into-39-in-c)

I have  a "String" that is "39.999%", I'd like to extract "39" and % out of it.

Similarly, a 0.9% would yield 0%